# UWIN grep on windows, wildards failure

Tags: windows, grep, wildcards

I have the UWIN unix tools, and I can't grep a whole dir full of files with *.

```
grep term *
```

gives

```
grep: *: can not open [No such file or directory]
```

whether in cmd.exe or powershell (I hate this windows crap).
The wildcards seem to work with other stuff (ls, dir,etc.)

Ah, so the question is, why? Is there some other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative set of Unix tools for Windows is [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS).  If you have msysgit installed, you might already have this on your machine.

Comment: I have gitbash, gitshell, some crappy gui git tool...never heard of msysgit. I'll have to look at that. I'm seeing it mentioned here a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell :)

```
    PS C:\> get-childitem c:\windows\system32\*.txt -recurse | select-string -pattern "Microsoft" -casesensitive
```

Straight from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx)